# Filebeat : drop fields kubernetes again again

Tags: kubernetes, kibana, filebeat, elk

I m trying to remove some fields, I use filebeat 7.14 on Kubernetes
I tried as described in the doc

```
processors:
  - drop_fields:
      when:
        contains
      fields: ["host.os.name", "host.os.codename", "host.os.family"]
      ignore_missing: false
```

```
container failed "ERROR   instance/beat.go:989    
Exiting: Failed to start crawler: 
starting input failed: Error while initializing input: 
missing or invalid condition
failed to initialize condition"
```

ignore_missing still messing

```
- drop_fields:
      fields: ["host.os.name", "host.os.codename", "host.os.family"]
```

fields are still present

Answer (score 0):

you don't seem to have a condition set under the `when`. take a look at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/7.14/defining-processors.html#conditions and make sure you've got something for it to match

Comment: there is a condition below when "contains"

Comment: yeah but contains what? you haven't defined that